# Programmatically enabling provisioning api?

Tags: google-admin-settings-api

Just wondering whether it's possible to enable provisioning api without having to manually open the Admin Console.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. I thought of maybe the reseller can use reseller API to enable provisioning API for their domains, but it is restricted.  You have to log in to Admin console to enable it manually.

Comment: Would be so nice if Reseller API had an optional parameter of "EnableProvisioningAPI" on Customer.Insert.

Comment: Of course, you'd need a way to get to the provisioning api without any users after that.